# Add TextMeshPro component to gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, textmeshpro

When i add TextMeshPro component to gameobject my gameobject and mesh filter disappear. What is the problem?

```cs
private TextMeshPro m_text;

    void Awake()
    {
        m_text = gameObject.GetComponent<TextMeshPro>() ? gameObject.GetComponent<TextMeshPro>() : gameObject.AddComponent<TextMeshPro>();

        m_text.font = Resources.Load<TMP_FontAsset>("Fonts & Materials/LiberationSans SDF");

        m_text.fontSharedMaterial = Resources.Load<Material>("Fonts & Materials/LiberationSans SDF - Drop Shadow");

        m_text.fontSize = 4;

        m_text.text = "Player name";

        m_text.transform.position = gameObject.transform.position;

        m_text.rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(3f, 3f);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        m_text.transform.Rotate(Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles - m_text.transform.eulerAngles);
    }
```

Mesh filter and material was changed to TMP

Comment: MeshFilter was just deleted*

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/RqEbMFm added images. before/after launch game

Comment: It does use a MeshFilter, but it is hidden (used internally by the 3d text).  If you try to add another MeshFilter you get a warning that the component is already added.  Why do you need another MeshFilter on the same GameObject?  Instead, make the 3d text a separate object.